# How to list handles of each pages in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1.9

How to list the various handles in a page in Magento 2.1.x.
In Magento 1 this is the code used to get the list of handles :var_dump(app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());.How to use it in Magento 2

Comment: You want just a simple list, or something more special?

Comment: I need to print layout of each pages separately when it loads

Comment: so printing the current page layout? try  `echo $this->getRequest()->getFullActionName();`

Comment: @vlad actually i m  planning to add the code in index.php file in root folder.When i pasted the given code it is showing as undefined method error

Comment: I would suggest adding it to a PHTML file

Answer (score 2):

You can use it directly in Magento2 block like below

```
var_dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```